# tableview cell action issue xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

So I am creating this todo app. It is on a tableview. And each cell when tapped or clicked should take you to a ask.com search to search for the item if it is not clear what the Item is. I have gotten it to search on ask.com with the code I have written. But the issue that I have coming up is that after the first click. The page doesn't refresh or update. I can click on the second or third cell and it wont search for what is in that particular cell. It keeps showing what is in the first cell. and won't change. I have tried clearing cells and it still keeps going through as the old search from the first time. Ex: Cell 1 : cleaning products Cell 2: a bike Cell 3: dog. No matter what cell I pick it will only show cleaning product. Even if I change cell 1 to another item.  How can I fix this. Source code would be amazing.

```
  import UIKit
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController, NewCellDelegate, {
 var news:[News]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadData()

    func loadData() {
        news = [News]()
        news = DataManager.loadAll(News.self).sorted(by: {$0.createdAt < $1.createdAt})
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

    @IBAction func Save(_ sender: Any) {
        let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "ADD", message: "TODO", preferredStyle: .alert)
        addAlert.addTextField { (textfield:UITextField) in
            textfield.placeholder = "TODO"
        }

        addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
            guard let title = addAlert.textFields?.first?.text else {return}
            let newsave = News(title: title, completed: false, createdAt: Date(), itemIdentifier: UUID())
            newsave.saveItem()
            self.news.append(newsave)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0), section: 0)

            self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)


        }))

        addAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(addAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

};

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return news.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell
    cell.delegte = self

    let news = self.news[indexPath.row]

    cell.label.text = news.title

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:
        NSIndexPath) {
    //getting the index path of selected row
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    //getting the current cell from the index path
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell

    //getting the text of that cell
    let TODO = currentCell.textLabel!.text

    let appURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.ask.com/web?q=\
        (TODO))&o=0&qo=homepageSearchBox)")

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appURL! as URL) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(appURL! as URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(appURL! as URL)
        }

    }
}
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it relates to search content change this

```
 let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!)! as UITableViewCell
```

to

```
 let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! NewTableViewCell
```

&&&  change this

```
 let TODO = currentCell.textLabel!.text
```

to

```
let TODO = currentCell.label.text
```